# Delete image in the gallery after camera intent photo taken

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i'm creating an image cropping application and i want to delete the image automatically in the gallery after the camera intent photo taken.
my goal is to delete automatically the image taken from the camera app after cropping the image.

this is the code for opening camera

```
private void pickCamera() {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "NewPic");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,"Image to Text");

    image_uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,image_uri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE);

}





protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE) {
            CropImage.activity(data.getData()).setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).start(this);
        }

        if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE){
            CropImage.activity(image_uri).setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).start(this);

        }
    }

    if(requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

            mPreviewIv.setImageURI(resultUri);
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)mPreviewIv.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();



            TextRecognizer recognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();

            if(!recognizer.isOperational()){

                Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Comment: You should also share the code of how you opened the camera intent for capturing

Comment: my bad, i editted my post already

Comment: Start by using `FileProvider` instead of `getContentResolver().insert()`. The reason why your image is "in the gallery" is because you put it there using `MediaStore`. If you stop using `MediaStore`, it is very likely that your image will never wind up in the gallery.